Wiremock should not trust backend endpoint when proxying
I am running Wiremock as a standalone process to proxy all requests to "https://mybackend.net". Why the connection is trusted (I expect a SSL certificate problem)?
This is the command used to start up Wiremock:
java -jar wiremock-standalone-3.9.1.jar --port 9000 --proxy-all https://mybackend.net --enable-browser-proxying

And this is the output:
version:                      3.9.1
port:                         9000
proxy-all:                    https://mybackend.net
preserve-host-header:         false
preserve-user-agent-proxy-header:false
enable-browser-proxying:      true
trust-all-proxy-targets:      false <----------------
ca-keystore:                  /Users/myuser/.wiremock/ca-keystore.jks
ca-keystore-type:             jks
disable-banner:               false
no-request-journal:           false
verbose:                      false

Why Wiremock is trusting the connection? Isn't trust-all-proxy-targets flag indicating that the connection shouldn't be trusted?
When I use curl directly to the backend I get a SSL certificate issue:
curl -X GET "https://mybackend.net/somepath"

curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

And when I go through Wiremock I get a successful response:
curl -X GET "http://localhost:9090/somepath"

I was expecting to see a certificate issue.
Edit - I have verified in the keystore (/Users/myuser/.wiremock/ca-keystore.jks) that the certificate for the backend server is not there

I think this is the first time anyone's ever complained about not getting a certificate error :-)

--trust-all-proxy-targets only applies to forward (browser) proxying. In your CLI command you're enabling both forward and reverse proxying but using reverse proxying to make the request, meaning WireMock will always trust the endpoint specified.

is there a way to make WireMock validate the target certificate when it acts s reverse proxy (configuring a custom CA) ? Otherwise it is susceptible to a MITM attack, isn't it?

Sure, in principle it could be MITM'd, but what attacker would ever bother going after your test tooling in this way, realistically?

You can now swap out the HTTP client for your own implementation via WireMock's programmatic options, so you could use that to enforce certificate validation if it really was required.
